# Instant notification for Master Card Payment gateway MiGS

Tags: paypal-ipn, mastercard

I'm currently integrating our system with MiGS, I received all documentation and example code from Bank,

My issue is that  they don't seem to be implementing IPN the same way PayPal does, they only request for a return URL to which the user is redirected after payment, however this URL cannot be used as an IPN listener on our side, simply because if the user closes the browser before being redirected, then our system will Never be notified of the payment,

Any help of how IPN is handled in MiGS?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just got answer from the bank that MiGS don't support IPN,so if the user closes the browser before being redirected back to our return URL, we can  alternatively run Query DR , which would Query the status of the payment